# How do I take a photo of a animals in a shaded glass boxes behind a glass panel?

Tags: shooting-technique, glass

How do I take photo of an animal in the following situation

- A very bright room.
- The bright room has many smaller rooms.
- Each smaller room has a few shaded glass boxes.
- There are two rows of shaded glass boxes. The first row is nearer to the smaller room's glass panel
- Each shaded glass box has the creature to be photographed

Illustration (Top view)

[image]

- Black refers to the wall of the smaller room (or the opaque side of the shaded glass box)
- Pink refers to the area inside the bright room.
- Blue refers to the shaded glass.
- Yellow refers to the glass panel of the smaller room.

Also note the following:

- No big tripod. (Small tripod allowed)
- the creature can move about inside the shaded glass box but quite slowly.

Comment: Is flash allowed? || If you accept the 1st answer given within about an hour of asking you will sometimes discourage people who care about reputation. Best to wait a day or so to see what comes. || Camera lens as close as possible to yellow glass and at an angle. Mask or hood around lens to keep incident light off glass around where lens is looking through glass. If flash allowed you can often use flash to illuminate through blue glass if angle is OK to carry reflection away from you.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I never thought that accept the 1st answer given within an hour of asking can discourage people who care about reputation. I have posted a discussion at http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3790/when-should-i-put-a-tick-on-an-answer as I would like to be fair to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have plenty of light for good exposures, but from your diagram it may be trickier to find a good composition without a tele lens. So you may be restricted in how large an aperture you will be able to use and, therefore, may need to rely on higher ISOs.

I'd also look out for reflections in the many glasses on the way, and a polarizer may not be able to remove all of them since the lights are different and from various directions.

If you can get close enough to the first window (the yellow one above) you may try using a circular (not petal shaped) lens hood and place the hood directly over the window surface in order to at least not get reflections from the first window.